# Special Case of String interned in Java

Tags: java

I have following two lines in Java code :

```
String str = new String("My place")
String str1 = new String("My place")
```

It is clear that new String("My place") creates two object,one due to **interning** and another due to **new** but i am confused as here the argument is having same literal so whether same interned object is being used by str1 resulting in 3 objects or different resulting in 4 objects

Comment: 3 objects...because of the literal being the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interning of string literals is automatic in Java, so the same interned object will be used in both constructors, so there will be three objects, not four.

Answer (score -2):

same interned object will be used by str1 resulting in 3 objects , try to undertnad using equals methods

Comment: `str1` has nothing to do with interning, and what exactly does the `equals()` method have to do with the question?

Comment: let's assume class String has a field, private char[] data. Then after String str= new String("xyz"); the following will be true: str.equals("xyz"), str != "xyz", str.data == "xyz".data. I.e. both fields refer to the same array.My point is use equals() and == method to understand object creation in string pool and heap.